# Google Script Error - UrlFetchApp with Facebook Graph Api brings to many urlfetch

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i wrote simple code to get some information from the facebook graph api

```
function event_host(url) {
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  var access_token = "xxx";
  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://graph.facebook.com/"+url+"?access_token="+access_token);
  var object = Utilities.jsonParse(jsondata.getContentText());
  return object.owner.name;

  //ERROR too many urlfetch oder invoked to many times...
}
```

It worked liked a charme for an hour or so - than it stopped working with the ERROR Message: Fehler: Fehler beim URL-Abruf, da zu viele Anfragen an die angegebene URL gesendet werden.

Failure calling the URL, to many url fetch.

I tried to put "Utilities.sleep - but that did not help.
Any Idea how i can solve that problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Facebook for some reason blocks the fetch requests from Google Scripts. As a workaround, you may use some sort of proxy service and Facebook would allow it.

Comment: Any suggestion? I found a lot of scripts/tutorials where people seem to fetch directly without proxy from facebook and it worked for me too for about an hour before it stopped working because of that error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the sleep time between every fetch request. You may do like do like this,

```
var sleepTime = Math.random()*1000;
Utilities.sleep(sleepTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the 'useIntranet' option as a parameter to fetchResult and that seemed to solve the issue.

```
var options = {"useIntranet" : true};
var fetchResult = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fullURL, options);
```